# How to play MovieClip animation which is not on the main timeline

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, timeline, tween

[image]On my main timeline, I have a 'background' layer, a 'play' layer an an 'actions' layer. In the 'play' layer, there is a MovieClip whose instance name is playButton. All layers on the main timeline only have one frame.

In the actions layer on the main timeline, this is what is there

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.Float;

function playButtonClicked(evt:MouseEvent) {
    backgroundMC.analysisScreenMC.play();
}

playButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playButtonClicked);
```

In the background layer, there is a MovieClip called backgroundMC. Inside backgroundMC (if you double click backgroundMC) there is another MovieClip whole instance name is analysisScreenMC and it has two layers, an 'actions' layer and an 'answers' layer. Both these layers have 13 frames. The 'answers' layer is a motion tween, and basically makes analysisScreenMC fade out to 50% opacity. The actions layer in analysisScreenMC is just this

```
stop();
```

(without stop(); the animation plays over and over again)

Now, when I run the animation, nothing happens even if I click the play button. 
Any idea why?

Note: I also tried doing this

```
function playButtonClicked(evt:MouseEvent) {
    trace('clicked');
    backgroundMC.analysisScreenMC.play();
}
```

and it does in fact trace 'clicked' every time I click the play button.

Below is an image of the timeline of analysisScreenMC.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function playButtonClicked(evt:MouseEvent) {
    backgroundMC.analysisScreenMC.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

Also have stop() in first frame of the action layer of analysisScreenMC and remove the remaining frames of the action layer.

Comment: hm, I tried it and it doesn't work, it still doesn't do anything even if I click the play button.

Comment: Also have stop() in first frame of the action layer of analysisScreenMC and remove the remaining frames of the action layer.

Comment: hm, same problem occurs even when I try it with the edit and put stop(); in the first frame while deleting all the other frames on the actions layer in analysisScreenMC.

Comment: Did you try removing remaining frames of the action layer of analysisScreenMC except first frame?

Comment: can you attach the screenshot of timeline of your analysisScreenMC  ?

Comment: Hm, i'm at work and imagehosting sites are blocked. I'm guessing there is no way for me to upload an image from my computer unless I use an image hosting site right?

Comment: You can attach image in your question itself.

Comment: hm I attached it, it doesn't seem to be appearing but when I click 'edit' on my question post, I can see the link.

Comment: As per the screenshot it has one frame with stop() action , So gotoAnd Play(2) should work. Is your animation playing if you remove stop()?

Comment: I agree, it Should work but it desn't even if I use gotoAndPlay(2). If I remove stop();, the animation does play over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

In playButtonClicked, try:

```
trace("backgroundMC="+ backgroundMC+", backgroundMC.analysisScreenMC="+ backgroundMC.analysisScreenMC);
```

This will show you if these movieClips exist.

Comment: this is what it traces. 'backgroundMC=[object analysisScreenInside_1], backgroundMC.analysisScreenMC=[object MovieClip]'... is it wrong? analysisScreenMC is the instance name of analysisScreenInside.

Comment: That looks ok.  backgroundMC.analysisScreenMC is a MovieClip as it should be.  Maybe look at the timeline in analysisScreenMC to make sure it's ok?  Or try (placing it on and) playing it from the main timeline to be sure.

Comment: hm what do ou mean my 'try playing it from the main timeline'? The MC is in the timeline inside the backgroundMC which is in the main timeline.

Comment: placing it on the main timeline and playing it (comment edited).  Are there any scripts in analysisScreenMC that may prevent it from playing?  And as Subash mentioned, gotoAndPlay is the more typical way to do it.